# How can I check that a string is a property a particular interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I do have a real-world circumstance where I needed to refer to a property by name using a string literal.  I wanted to make that type-safe, and it feels like in TypeScript, that should be possible.  Consider the following simplified example:

```
interface MyInterface {
    foo: string,
}

const barName = <keyof MyInterface>'bar'    // No error?
const bazName = 'baz' as keyof MyInterface  // No error?
const bopName:keyof MyInterface = 'bop' // Finally, an error!
```

I believe the answer is that the `<>` and `as` operations in TypeScript are "type assertions" not "type cast attempts".  The first two consts above are basically saying, "trust me, this *is* a key of MyInterface", while the third const is attempting a typed assignment, and failing.

I'd like to know if I'm right about that, and if so, if there's some other in-line way to test that a string literal is a keyof a given interface, without making a temp variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right about the reason you don't get an error on the first two `const` declarations.

The only way to get an error without an explicit type annotation on the variable it to use a helper function:

```
interface MyInterface {
    foo: string,
}
const key = <T>(o: keyof T) => o;
const barName = key<MyInterface>('bar')    // error
const fooName = key<MyInterface>('foo')    // ok
```

You could also leve the `const` declaration as is, the `const` will be typed as the string literal type associated with the string literal and you will get an error first time you use it to index into an instance of `MyInterafce`, although this might nto be applicable in all cases.

Comment: Thanks.  The function is a great solution and has the desired compile-time effect.  It unfortunately doesn't melt away during compilation, and ends up as a function call in the resulting JavaScript.  For those curious about the performance implications, there's a relevant discussion [on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/661#issuecomment-374473607) about this sort of simple function's run-time performance.  (tl;dr: it's got zero impact on performance)